# PHP html table output

Tags: php

I'm having trouble changing the output of the following:

```
echo "<td>" . $row['NetworkSettings'] . "</td>";
```

displays this: `00:0C:29:44:D8:A1|192.168.1.1|192.168.1.170,`

but I want it to display this 192.168.1.170
any help would be appreciated

Comment: where you get this value from ? `$row['NetworkSettings']`

Answer (score 6):

```
$arr = explode ("|" ,  $row['NetworkSettings'] );
echo $arr[2];
```